# How to add image in Picture Box (C#)

Tags: c#

I created simple Car Dealer project with SQL Database and stored some images in there. There are different car models and pictures. Added DataGrid and PictureBox in my Windows Form.

***Windows Form - In right PictureBox, in left DataGrid:***
[image: Windows Form screenshot]

**Now I want to add image to this PictureBox when I click DataGrid cell. Like when I click on first row it has to show me picture of this model.** How can I do this with code? Can you give any advice?

Comment: You would have to use the onclick event of the cell in the grid. From there you would load the image into the picture box. So when you click the grid cell it will load the picture.. you can do this on as many grid cells as you like with different images

Comment: What do you want to know: How to listen to the ClickEvent? How to get the corresponding image? How to show the image?